# Arrayindex out of bound comes when collapse the expandble list group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I m using the expandble list view and collapsing it using expand.collapse but its throwing ans exception-
Arrayindexoutofbound.

```
ExpandableListView  mExpandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(pause!=1234){

                        mExpandableList.collapseGroup(pause);
                    System.out.println(pause+" CLICKED");
                }
                    pause=groupPosition;
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: I was seeing the same thing, and I believe it is because we were trying to collapse a group while another group is being expanded at the same time.  It's probably either an Android limitation or a bug.  I ended up handling the collapse of the old group in the onGroupExpanded method of the adapter as mentioned online in several google searches on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you use like this

```
@Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(pause!=1234){

                    mExpandableList.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                System.out.println(pause+" CLICKED");
            }
                pause=groupPosition;
                return false;
            }
```

or use this Method if it is suitable for your case.

```
mExpandableList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

        }
    });
```